# Find the poles and residues of the complex function $f(z) =\frac{2z+1}{(z-1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been asked to find the poles and residues of the complex function $$f(z) =\frac{2z+1}{(z-1)^2}.$$

Would I be correct in saying that there is only one pole of order $2$ at $z = 1$ and therefore the use of the plural 'poles' is misleading?
And finally, how would I go about finding the residue of this order 2 pole as I have only worked with simple poles of order 1 until this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, $z=1$ is the only pole and it is of order $2$. As regards the residue evaluation note that
$$\frac{2z+1}{(z-1)^2}=\frac{2z-2+3}{(z-1)^2}=\frac{3}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{2}{z-1}.$$
Now recall the [definition of residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Definition). Can you take it from here?

Comment: Checking your wiki link for the “definition of residue” I have navigated to the section about calculating residues for higher order poles and found that following their set formula, I obtain that the residue equates to 2. Can you verify that this is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. More directly, the residue is the coefficient of $1/(z-1)$ in the (Laurent) expansion of $f$ as series of powers of $(z-1)^k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thanks. And finally, the question asks “for which values of R does the following integral equal zero?” Where the integral is of f(z)dz and the domain of integration is the circle centred at 0 with radius R. 
Would I be correct in saying that this is for all R < 1 since from my understanding of the residue theorem, this would be sufficient to exclude the consideration of the pole at z=1 when adding the 2pi*i terms?

Comment: I would say $R<1$, so that the pole is outside the disk.

Comment: Haha yes I just edited it before you commented to correct my mistake. Thanks for your help on this topic :)

Comment: You are welcome!